# Accessing http://example.com gives 502 Bad Gateway But http://example.com:3000 gives me the website

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment

I have a reactJS app running at port 3000 on a VPS. I am having difficult understanding why http://example.com is not working while http://example.com:3000 is working correctly. Below I have my nginx server configuration

```py
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # Enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Is there anything i missed? Thank you!

Comment: Is there anything in nginx' error log? Probably in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: not there isn't anything

Comment: Does `sudo nginx -t` give you any errors? `-t` runs a syntax check on nginx' configuration files. Does `error.log` exist at all? If not, it may be in a different location which you can find by finding the `error_log` directive from either this file or `nginx.conf`.

Comment: just tried it, it indicates that all OK and successful. The error.log exists but no errors related really